# When to drink when listening to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, fun, podcast

It's the holidays, what could be more fun than kicking back with your programming relatives, a few drinks and the Stack Overflow podcast?  Don't answer that, instead suggest rules for the Stack Overflow drinking game!

One rule per answer, the top votes will make the game.  I'll kick it off with this one:

Drink every time Jeff or Joel is interrupted by the other person.

Update: putting this question into wiki mode as requested in the comments.

Comment: Removed Downvote because of wiki, but I still think its completely unrelated to programming  "Where do you like to hike after posting on Stack Overflow?"
From faq:  What kind of questions can I ask here?

Programming questions, of course!

Comment: @Fry: yeah, it's completely OT. But it seems like we're due at least one a day, and i'd rather see a drinking question than yet another "what's your favorite X" post.

Comment: This would require me to listen to the podcast in the first place. :o

Comment: Bill K: it becomes wiki after 4 different people edit the Q.

Comment: Oh come on, it might be a bit meta and self-referential but closing it? Why hasn't someone closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts ?

Comment: So if this wasn't in the wiki, would someone else still have been able to close it?

Comment: @jblocksom: yeah, closing is independent of the wiki state of a post. Generally though, editors are a bit more permissive with CW posts.

Comment: Drink when somebody says 'This needs to be community wiki'

Comment: Genuis question.

Comment: I can't wait to jump on re-opening this question when the next person votes to close it.

Comment: @Simucal: I will be jumping right with you on this one ;) But how come you like this question and not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519954 ?

Comment: @VonC, because I honestly don't think that question even makes any sense.  It doesn't seem like a clever or good question and the community didn't seem to think so either.  This question is slightly meta, funny and anything that pokes fun at jeff OR joel and I'm game.

Comment: @Simucal: well, I guess we have to agree to disagree on "what makes sense" or "what is fun". Anyway, if this one get closed, leave me a comment on any on my answers: I will get back to this "question" and vote for reopen.

Comment: @Simucal ? Are you sleeping ? ;-) I have casted my vote for reopening. I did my part :)

Comment: Dang! I wanted to add "When they talk about Quality", but that would  be a different game. The one where you take Vicodin.

Comment: @lagerdalek - You want to kill off all the stackoverflow users?

Comment: @VonC, I was sleeping!  When it gets closed again I'll be sure to jump on the re-open.  Let me know.

Comment: @Unsliced, it should be closed

Comment: This post was mentioned on the podcast - that's enough reason to keep it open. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This is an utterly pointless 'fun' question that just encourages more questions like this. Yet if I were to ask it, it would have been closed poste haste.

Comment: This is a hilarious question, with good community response and some clever answers.  The secret is, you are only allowed to post this kind of stuff if your posts become a success.  If they don't, then oh well.  I say keep it open.

Comment: Heh... By rights, this should be closed. I mean, if there were a bot sent around to close things that met/failed to meet certain criteria, this would be closed. It'll stay open though, because we actually need a *few* of these. Not a lot; one every quarter is fine. If only SO had a Lounge forum...

Comment: And... voted for re-opening. Again. Still around Simucal ?

Comment: Voted to re-open again.

Comment: This is an epicly fun question.  We have jon-skeet facts, we have some others.  If it seems immensely successful I think our programmer-pedantic ways should take a back seat and let it stand.  Besides, it is at least SO related ;)

Comment: Offensive, huh? I wonder why.

Comment: This question needs to be closed again, "fun" doesn't seem like much of a justification to pollute the front page, over and over again.

Comment: This comment thread is more entertaining than the answers

Comment: I've never listened to the podcast and after reading these answers I don't need to...thanks for the summary, keep up the good work. ;)

Comment: When either Joel or Jeff say, "Hi Bob."

Answer (score 228):

Whenever, after a 10 minute comment by Joel, Jeff leaves 3 seconds of dead air and then says, "Yeah."

Comment: God, if anything summed up the podcast more than this comment I don't know what it is.  Jeff and Joel make an entertaining podcast, so don't get me wrong.  But this is dead on.

Comment: I find Jeff's explanation for this (in Podcast #42) rather meaningless. "Trying to avoid dead air" for a podcast that you can edit it out of in post-production.. c'mon Jeff.. just pay attention to Joel once in awhile and respond with something meaningful.

Comment: @romandas, yeah, that's pretty crazy. Why would someone even use that as a justification?

Comment: In fairness, Jeff's gotten much better about this over time. Don't get me wrong either, I love the podcast. Jeff & Joel are very bright and entertaining guys.

Comment: How about making an outline of topics beforehand so when one finishes up you're ready to move on to the next one?

Comment: I like Jeff more than I like Joel. May be because I can connect to his thoughts, or just may be because I like his voice. :)

Answer (score 102):

Whenever Joel mentions Excel and VBA.

Comment: Did you hear the podcast?  Joel says "I never mention Excel and VBA" after spending half the podcast talking about it.

Comment: OH GODDDD this is so funny!!!

Answer (score 68):

Whenever Atwood says "actually"... Drink!

Comment: actually, I don't say this that much.

Comment: Neah... I'd get drunk in no time..

Answer (score 68):

Whenever Joel forgets about the dedicated phone number of the podcast.

OR

Whenever Joel talks while a user question is playing.

Comment: LOL, he always talks during a user question.  Hilarious.

Comment: I think that's why they only want audio questions as its much easier to just blather over someone else's question while playing than while reading it. Eh, it's possible. :)

Answer (score 63):

Whenever Joel causes his computer to produce an alert sound, causing a brief confused pause.

Comment: This just happened in 42!

Answer (score 61):

Whenever Joel describes an original, brilliant, sophisticated way to improve Stack Overflow, and Jeff explains how that feature has been implemented and usable on the site for several days.

Answer (score 53):

Whenever FogCreek's interview process (or intern program) is mentioned.

Answer (score 51):

When Joel or Jeff says the podcast is only listened to by 4 or less people.

Comment: And chug if Joel says his Dad still listens!

Comment: They're up to 4 now?

Comment: @spoulson you and I are 2.  hobarid is 3, and his Dad is 4.  They might break 5 if Joel has a brother or sister.

Answer (score 48):

When Jeff uses the word "right" at the end of a sentence, right?

Comment: This one really drives me nuts. "I mean, so, basically, it's all relative, right? I mean, there's no point in testing if quality is something that undecidable, like, like... traveling salesman, right?"

Comment: Right                  .

Answer (score 47):

Whenever you hear the phrase "6 to 8 weeks"...Drink!

Answer (score 41):

When Jeff misuses the word literally :)

Comment: yeah a lot of people use the word "literally" in a figurative sense

Comment: hehe its a pet hate of mine, all in good jest though. I'm not trying to be mean :) Pobodies nerfect

Comment: I saw a newspaper article recently about a gun enthusiast. His wife said he "literally eats, sleeps, and breathes guns".

Comment: Yet no one has a problem with the use of "really" in a similar manner.

Comment: toast: interesting point. But no one says, "I'm so hungry I could really eat a horse." They say, "I'm really hungry," where really means genuinely or truly.

Comment: i have the same problem with "virtually".

Comment: You mean he literally misuses the word literally, on literally every podcast?

Answer (score 38):

Whenever Jeff chuckles, realizing he's about to say something that might piss people off.

Comment: good one! you can already tell the next sentence will be about PHP or someone caring about the quality of their code...

Answer (score 30):

Whenever Jeff disses PHP.

Comment: I think you mean Jeff - he's the big PHP hater, not Joel

Comment: And yet he likes VB.

Comment: @Kristopher Johnson good shot

Answer (score 27):

Whenever Rock Band is mentioned.

Answer (score 27):

Whenever Jeff says "Jon Skeet".

Answer (score 25):

Whenever you hear "smart" and "get the things done".

Answer (score 22):

Whenever Joel and Jeff argue about the importance of knowing how to program in C

Answer (score 19):

Whenever Jeff laughs at his own comments. A double drink if he laughs mid-sentence.

Comment: LOL @ mid-sentence double up

Answer (score 18):

When, during the next Stack Overflow podcast, Jeff Atwood criticizes this question as a diversion to the site and a poor practice during programming.

Then Joel reminds him that drinking is fun. :)

Comment: I never meta answer as good as this one.

Answer (score 16):

Whenever Joel says they're going long, I'll have to edit this.

Or

Just every time you hear 'Fog Creek' - bonus drink when it's about their new office.  *(:=

Answer (score 15):

When Joel says "but.. but"

Answer (score 14):

Whenever Joel and Jeff trash TDD but have zero experience in it.

Comment: But they are right!

Answer (score 12):

Whenever Joel says something Jeff thinks is stupid or boring but doesn't want to offend Joel, Jeff says "Cool. That's really cool."

Answer (score 12):

Whenever Jeff prefixes some term with "quote-unquote".  I can picture him doing the air quotes thing with his hands.

Comment: Would you say "Quote unquote testing" or perhaps more correctly "Quote testing unquote"? Do people say that?

Answer (score 11):

Whenever there's a reference to the reputation system.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever Jeff says "postmortem," talks about C, talks about Steve Yegge, or especially when Jeff uses the word "pathology." As well, when Joel talks about psychology (yes, most of us have taken Psych 101). That's pretty much it. :)

Comment: Pathology! Ouch!

Answer (score 11):

Whenever Jeff makes some huge error about computer science, but excuses it by saying he 'doesn't know math'

Answer (score 10):

Whenever Joel says Jeff needs to learn C.

Answer (score 9):

When Jeff mispronounces something.

Comment: Is it really Sequel Server? I sound it out: S. Q. L. Meh.

Comment: that's not what I am talking about.

Comment: Oh this rule would be a ... debacle. lol

Answer (score 8):

Whenever an algorithmic complexity class is incorrectly defined.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever either/both mention the vast communities they bring to the table.

I love 'em both, and read 'em both, but I feel so used after those comments :p

Answer (score 6):

Whenever Jeff says "on some level...".

Answer (score 5):

Whenever Jeff does that fake forced laugh.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever Jeff or Joel say "basically"

Answer (score 5):

Whenever they say Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's like picking "The Ship" when playing "The Love Boat Drinking Game".

Comment: Clearly you love to drink :)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever either says "RAID".

Answer (score 5):

Whenever Joel says the name of a caller right before playing the recording of the caller saying the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Joel pronounces "wiki" as "wee-key"

Comment: Actually, that's how the Hawaiian work (meaning "fast") is pronounced, according to the Wikipedia article on "Wiki." So yeah, Wee-kee-pee-dee-uh. Even though saying that makes me feel like the Swedish Chef from the Muppets.

Comment: How do you pronounce it? I pronounce it just the same as Joel.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever Joel says "Now I'm going to get hate mail from the $PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE users for the next week."

Answer (score 4):

Another one: Whenever Joel and Jeff (mostly Joel, though) talk about how math is taught wrong, how people shouldn't care about algebra and calculus but should just go straight to Linear Algebra, Topology, Queuing Theory, etc. However, be sure not to learn anything in depth as that would be hard (like C). The reason this is so is because most of the math is useless and apparently nobody ever made a money using Linear Algebra (wow). ::shrugs::

Comment: I thought the same.  A fair chunk of 3D rendering algorithms use linear algebra.  Business apps?  Not so much.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever they start sounding like Beavis and Butthead.

Comment: That one made me laugh!

Answer (score 4):

Drink when Joel mentions that he worked at Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Jeff says, "I'm not saying that I'm" and then cites some impossibly high standard of programming genius.  He's not saying he is that genius, mind you, but he seems to want to raise the possibility . . .

Answer (score 3):

Whenever they mention the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Joel mentions that he went to Yale.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever they talk about chairs and/or C pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever one interrupts the other :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Joel or Jeff mention specific Stack Overflow users; this should net at least one drink / podcast.

Answer (score 2):

When one of them snorts!

Answer (score 2):

Trail of breadcrumbs...

Answer (score 1):

Drink when Jeff says "on some level".

Answer (score 1):

Whenever they talk about critical user mass.

Whenever Joel talks about a project's velocity.